# Plot a Complex Polar Number as Magnitude Arrow and Phase Dot on a Circle

Tags: plotting

Given a complex number, `z = r*exp(i*psi)`, how can I use Mathematica to plot the magnitude and phase on a circle? I've put together an example using the following code[image]:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}], Red, 
  Point[{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}]}, Axes -> True]
```

However, with Mathematica's new complex plotting options, I feel like there is a better way to do it but I haven't been able to figure it out. `ComplexListPlot` has nice `PolarAxes` options, but I am unsure if I can use that with an arrow whose length I set. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
r = 3;
ψ = Pi/4;
ComplexListPlot[{r Exp[I ψ]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red],
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}},
 PolarGridLines -> {{{ψ, Directive[Opacity[1], Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[Large]]}}, 
  {{r, Gray}}}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

For multiple points and arrows:

```
r = 3;
angles = {Pi/4, 2 Pi/3};
colors = {Red, Magenta};
arrowcolors = {Blue, Green};

ComplexListPlot[{r Exp[I #]} & /@ angles, 
  BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10],
  PlotRange -> 1.2 r {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
  PlotStyle -> colors,
  PolarGridLines -> {MapThread[{#, Directive[Opacity[1], #2, Thick, 
        Arrowheads[Large]]} &, {angles, arrowcolors}], {{r, Gray}}}] /. 
 Line -> (Arrow[#, {0, .15 r}] &)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[PolarPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html) is what You are looking for.

From the examples this one might be cool:

```
PolarPlot[Floor[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, PointSize[Medium]}]
```

[image]

ListPolarPlot offers the example for the polar grid:

```
ListPolarPlot[Sin[Range[0, 4 Pi, 0.1]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Grid"}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow
```

"]

[image]

For the arrow, there is no new built-in available. The enhancement is

```
AnnotatedArrow[p_, q_, 
  label_] := {Arrowheads[{{-.1, 0}, {.1, .5, 
     Graphics[Inset[Style[label, Medium], {Center, Top}]]}, {.1, 1}}],
   Arrow[{p, q}]}
Graphics[{AnnotatedArrow[{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, "diameter = 2"], Circle[]}]
```

[image]

Look up the documentation for Arrow for further inspiration:
[Arrow](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html)

[`PlanarAngle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarAngle.html) provides some convention for the usage. That is new in 12. [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html) add vector addition conventions. [`AngleVector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AngleVector.html) represents the mathematical object central in Your question. It can be input to [`ListPolarPot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html)

[`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) or [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html).

A solution in ComplexListPlot is

```
Show[ComplexListPlot[{0, (1 + I)/Sqrt@2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", 0.1}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic], 
 Graphics[Circle[]], PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html) to interactively set the angle and the radius:

```
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{pt = {3, 3}}, Panel @ 
  Graphics[{Dynamic @ Circle[{0, 0}, Norm[pt]], Point[{0, 0}], 
     Blue, Arrowheads[Large], Dynamic[Arrow[{{0, 0}, pt}]],
     Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point@Dynamic[pt], 
     Locator[Dynamic[pt], None], 
     Gray, Dashed, Dynamic[Line@{{pt[[1]], 0}, pt, {0, pt[[2]]}}], 
     Black, Dynamic @ Text[Style[HoldForm[# E^(#2 I)]& @@ 
       Round[{Norm[pt], ArcTan @@ pt}, .1], 14],
       pt 1.1, If[Abs[ArcTan @@ pt] <= Pi/2, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}]]}, 
    Axes -> True,
    Ticks -> Dynamic[Round[{{pt[[1]]}, {pt[[2]]}}, 1/10]], 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"Re", "Im"}), 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]